# Trying to make a class codable in Swift but it is not the correct format?

Tags: swift, swift4, codable, decodable, encodable

I am creating a class that conforms to codable.

I have this:

```
import Foundation

class Attribute : Decodable {

  var number: Int16
  var label: String?
  var comments: String?

  init(number:Int16, label:String?, comments:String?) {
    self.number = number
    self.label = label
    self.comments = comments
  }

  // Everything from here on is generated for you by the compiler
  required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let keyedContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    number = try keyedContainer.decode(Int16.self, forKey: .number)
    label = try keyedContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .label)
    comments = try keyedContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .comments)
  }

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case number
    case label
    case comments
  }

}

extension Attribute: Encodable {

  public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(number, forKey: .number)
    try container.encode(label, forKey: .label)
    try container.encode(comments, forKey: .comments)
  }
}
```

This is apparently fine.

I create an instance of `Attribute` and encode it using:

```
  let newAttribute = Attribute.init(number:value.number, label:value.label, comments:value.shortcut)
```

Then I create an array of these attributes and encode that array using

```
  let array = try JSONEncoder().encode(array)
```

This will encode the array of `Attribute` to `Data`.

Then I try to convert the `Data` object back to the array of `Attribute` using this:

```
let array = try JSONDecoder().decode(Attribute.self, from: data) as! Array<Attribute>
```

First error I get is this:

> Cast from 'Attribute' to unrelated type 'Array< Attribute>' always fails

If I remove the cast part I catch this error when the decode tries...

> Optional("The data isn’t in the correct format.")

Any ideas?

Comment: Rather than `error.localizedDescription` print only `error`. It tells you exactly what's wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the array to decode, don't pass in the array element type, then try to force-cast that to an array, that doesn't make any sense. `YourType` and `Array<YourType>` are two different and completely unrelated types, so you cannot cast one to the other and you need to use the specific type when calling `JSONDecoder.decode(_:from:)`.

```
let array = try JSONDecoder().decode([Attribute].self, from: data)
```

Btw as already pointed out in your previous question, there is no need to manually write the `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)` methods or the `CodingKeys` `enum` since for your simple type, the compiler can auto-synthesise all of those for you. Also, if you used a `struct` instead of `class`, you'd also get the member wise initialiser for free.